# Amplifier Power Ratings

Tags: speakers, power, amplifier, impedance

I want to understand the rating of my Marantz PM6002 amp.

The backplate says:

```
System 1: 4 - 16 Ohms
System 2: 4 - 16 Ohms
1 + 2   : 8 - 16 Ohms
```

So looking at the backplate, am I within the stated rating if I connect a pair of speakers with nominal impedance of 8 Ohms on System 1.  I believe so as 8 Ohms in parallel (the left and right speakers will be in parallel right?) is 4 Ohms.  Am I correctly interpreting this?

Second what happens if I connect the same to System 2 at the same time?  Will this put too much load on the amplifier?  Would this then be the equivalent of 4 x 8 Ohm speakers in parallel i.e. only 2 Ohms.  This would mean the speakers would be sucking too much power from the amplifier making it potentially run too hot?

Comment: This is _incorrect_. "The left and right speakers will be in parallell, right?" - *NO*. The ohms rating is _per channel_. In your case two 8 Ω (L & R) speakers connected to system 1 and two 8 Ω speakers connected to system 2 would be fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yep, you're right, you'll be taking the impedance too low, there are pro amplifiers that could do that, that are "2 ohm stable" but this isn't one of them.

Sorry.